# Units of a log of a physical quantity

Tags: logarithms, unit-of-measure

So I have never actually found a good answer or even a good resource which discusses this so I appeal to experts here at stack exchange because this problem came up again today. What happens to the units of a physical quantity after I take its (natural) logarithm. Suppose I am working with some measured data and the units are Volts. Then I want to plot the time series on a log-scale, only the ordinate is on the log scale, not the abscissa. So the x-axis is definitely in time (seconds let's say) but what are the units on the y-axis? Will it be Volts or log(Volts) or something? If I square the quantities, then the units are squared too so what if I take the log? A rationale in addition to the answer will be appreciated as well.

I guess whatever the answer, the same goes for taking the exponential or sine of the data too, right?

Comment: The units remain the same, you are just scaling the axes. As an analogy, plotting a quantity on a polar chart doesn't change the quantities, it just 'warps' the display in some useful way. However, some quantities are 'naturally' expressed as logs (dB, for example), but these are always dimensional quantities (sometimes implicitly referenced to a known quantity).

Comment: If $x = 0.5$ is measured in some units, say, seconds, then taking the log actually means $\ln (0.5s/1s) = \ln (0.5)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Prince Ali, you wrote "same goes for taking the exponential or sine of the data too, right?" - what about taking the square as you mention - the square of length is area, which is not length.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Overall, the argument $x$ of $\ln(x)$ must be unitless, and a log transformed quantity must be unitless. If $x = 0.5$ is measured in some units, say, seconds, then taking the log actually means $\ln(0.5s/1s) = \ln(0.5)$. See [this](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed1000476) for more information about other transcendental functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Love the paper, going into the permanent archives. Also explains why classic arguments (like anorton's response below) is wrong. I was surprised to learn that too.

Comment: The paper seems interesting, but I can't read it (not willing to pay $35 for it at the moment). Can you give a 25 words or less summary of their main argument? I read the abstract but they don't cover the rationale there.

Comment: @RobertDodier I found the aforementioned [article](http://www.chem.utoronto.ca/~cmatta/2011_JChemEdu_Dimensions_and_Logs_Matta_Massa_Gubskaya_Knoll.pdf) on Matta's (one of the authors) website.

Comment: @glebovg Thanks for the link. I read the paper, but I have to admit I'm doubtful about their conclusions. They don't have any kind of an argument as to exactly why transcendental functions must have dimensionless arguments; simply repeating the conclusion over and over isn't an argument. Stuff like log(10 meters) = log(10) + log(meters) doesn't make sense, they claim, but that's not a mathematical attitude, right? The mathematical approach would be to find a consistent interpretation of apparently-nonsensical expressions, or prove there cannot be one. Simply giving up isn't proof of anything.

Comment: This agrees with the [response to essentially the same question on the physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13061/82482), that the logarithm of a number with units (shown in plots all the time) actually means the logarithm of that number divided by the standard unit for that quantity.

Comment: This answer is correct, but is the exact opposite conclusion of the paper cited, likely because the paper is basically garbage.

Answer (score 15):

Logarithm of a quantity really only makes sense if the quantity is dimensionless, and then the result is also a dimensionless number.  So what you really plot is not $\log(y)$ but $\log(y/y_0)$ where $y_0$ is some reference quantity in the same units as $y$ (in this case $y_0 = $1 Volt).  Similarly
for $\exp$ and $\sin$.

Comment: or $p_0=2\times10^{-5}\,\rm Pa$ as in measuring sound-pressure level!

Comment: Fully right, that's how log are used in engineering (Decibel and alike)

Comment: If that is true, then why are we taking a log of numbers with units in every single engineering/physics class?

Answer (score 9):

In the expression $\ln{x}$, $x$ must be unitless.

This is because the log function is a series with x raised to differing powers.  For instance:

$$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k(-1+x)^k}{k}}$$ for $$|-1 + x| < 1$$

Let's say $x$ had units of meters (for example).  Then the first term in the series would have units of meters, the second term units of square meters, 3rd term in cubic meters, etc.  You can't add quantities with differing powers of units, thus $x$ must be unit-less.

The same argument applies for $|-1+x|\not<1$.